# Using addChildEventListener on Firebase database query android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using `addChildEventListener` for my chat application

```
Query chatRoot = Qref
            .child("Messages")
            .orderByChild("lobbykey")
            .equalTo(lobbykey);`
```

This is the query that I am using works fine to my knowledge, just a bit of idea on 
what I'm trying to do. I also have a constructor class for my list to place objects:

```
public ChatParameters(String userUID, String message, String imageURL, String sender, String lobbykey, String msgkey) {
    this.UserUID = userUID;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.message = message;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
    this.lobbykey = lobbykey;
    this.msgkey = msgkey;
}
```

The onchildadded listener works fine. When I tried it with just Toast, it make text works fine. But when i add the Chatparameters.class to get all the values it crashes

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
  for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    ChatParameters chatParameters = chat.getValue(ChatParameters.class); //i get the error here.
  }
}
```

this is the error logcat, it's refering to ChatParameters chatParameters = chat.getValue(ChatParameters.class);

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.woofy_nocco.testapp.ChatParameters
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.woofy_nocco.testapp.Chatroom$1.onChildAdded(Chatroom.java:78)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

this is what my database structure looks like

[database.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2YdP.png)

Comment: post your database structure and code line of getting reference to database

Comment: i added the picture just now, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

The `onChildAdded` method of your `ChildEventListener` is invoked on individual child nodes already. So most likely you don't need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` in there:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    ChatParameters chatParameters = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatParameters.class);
}
```

---

Explanation of the problem: 
By looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` the `chatSnapshot` will end up referring to individual properties of the chat message. So if your `ChatParameters` consists if a `text` property and a `message` property, the `chatSnapshot` will be point to that `text` or `message` property, and  `chatSnapshot.getValue()` will be a string. Since a `String` can't be converted to your `ChatParameters` class, the SDK throws an exception.

Comment: should i try catch this? cause im still getting crashes on the same line.

Comment: crash on same error or different one ? because this may be the right answer to your problem